# Simple helper for making things "disposable"

Tags: c#, callback

I often write small classes to make undisposable things *disposable* so that .NET can handle something automatically, like stopwatches or logs. I thought why not write a small helper that can be used instead of implementing a full class for simple things.

The `Usingifier` requries two delegates, one for the initialization and the other one for *cleaning-up*. *(null checks removed for brevity)*

```
class Usingifier<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Func<T> _initialize;
    private readonly Action<T> _cleanUp;
    private T _state;

    public Usingifier(Func<T> initialize, Action<T> cleanUp)
    {
        _initialize = initialize;
        _cleanUp = cleanUp;
    }

    public Usingifier<T> Initialize()
    {
        _state = _initialize();
        return this;
    }
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (_state != null)
        {
            _cleanUp(_state);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's an example with a `Stopwatch`

```
using (var autoStopwatch = new Usingifier<Stopwatch>(() => Stopwatch.StartNew(), sw => sw.Elapsed.Dump()))
{
    autoStopwatch.Initialize();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: *null checks removed for brevety* - why?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I find code without null checks more readable. I always have to cry when I add them or logging and a simple function with just a few lines becomes a huge null check and logging monster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little difficult to give a full review without the removed null checks, but I'll give an observation:

In `Dispose()`, you **depend** on `null` to be the value of `_state` to judge whether or not to call the cleanup action. That's all well and good, but you should likely then constrain the generic parameter `T` to be `class`

```
class Usingifier<T> : IDisposable where T : class
```

You also have an issue with multiple-disposals calling the cleanup action with the state - both probably being stale after the fact. The class should be considered unusable after the cleanup. Or at least unusable until the initialize function has been called again. Simple boolean should take care of that:

```
class Usingifier<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<T> _initialize;

    private readonly Action<T> _cleanUp;

    private bool _disposed;

    private T _state;

    public Usingifier(Func<T> initialize, Action<T> cleanUp)
    {
        _initialize = initialize;
        _cleanUp = cleanUp;
    }

    public Usingifier<T> Initialize()
    {
        _state = _initialize();
        _disposed = false;
        return this;
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;

        if (_state != null)
        {
            _cleanUp(_state);
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to also put in some sort of nice (optional) automatic disposal if `T` itself happens to be `IDisposable`. Here's a quick take on that:

```
class Usingifier<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<T> _initialize;

    private readonly Action<T> _cleanUp;

    private readonly bool _autoDispose;

    private bool _disposed;

    private T _state;

    public Usingifier(Func<T> initialize, Action<T> cleanUp, bool autoDispose = false)
    {
        _initialize = initialize;
        _cleanUp = cleanUp;
        _autoDispose = autoDispose;
    }

    public Usingifier<T> Initialize()
    {
        _state = _initialize();
        _disposed = false;
        return this;
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;

        if (_state != null)
        {
            _cleanUp(_state);
        }

        if (_autoDispose && _state is IDisposable disposable)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I had a couple more thoughts: perhaps expose `_state` via a property (can then be accessed within your `using` scope) and then perhaps extracting an interface for the whole caboodle for mocking purposes during unit testing. Behold:

```
interface IUsingifier<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    T State { get; }

    Usingifier<T> Initialize();
}

class Usingifier<T> : IUsingifier<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<T> _initialize;

    private readonly Action<T> _cleanUp;

    private readonly bool _autoDispose;

    private bool _disposed;

    public Usingifier(Func<T> initialize, Action<T> cleanUp, bool autoDispose = false)
    {
        _initialize = initialize;
        _cleanUp = cleanUp;
        _autoDispose = autoDispose;
    }

    public T State { get; private set; }

    public Usingifier<T> Initialize()
    {
        State = _initialize();
        _disposed = false;
        return this;
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;

        if (State != null)
        {
            _cleanUp(State);
        }

        if (_autoDispose && State is IDisposable disposable)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oooh nice catch with the multiple-disposal problem - that's a violation of `IDisposable` implementation guidelines =)

Comment: I was going to use it with a `Mutex` that is an `IDisposable` so this is definitely a good catch.

Comment: I did it with C# 7 like this `if (_state is IDisposable disposable) disposable.Dispose();` but I like the `autoDispose` flag.

Comment: I was wondering if I could load this up with some C#7 goodness :)

Comment: Don't throw an exception when an object is disposed multiple times. [`IDisposable.Dispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) is specifically documented to be callable more than once.

Comment: Excellent point. I screwed up in where I put that detection. Will fix when back at my desk.

Comment: ...and that being said, it might behoove us to put a check in `Initialize` to only process it once per Initialize..Dispose cycle.